# JavaScript reduce to make an array group

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this group method:

```
function groupByRange(products) {
    products.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.rangeCode - b.rangeCode
    });

    let groups = products.reduce(function (accumulator, product) {
        (accumulator[product['rangeCode']] = accumulator[product['rangeCode']] || []).push(product);
        return accumulator;
    }, {});

    console.log(groups);

    return groups;
}
```

which creates an object similar to this:

```
{
    TEST: [{...}],
    TEST2: [{...}]
}
```

I would prefer to create something long the lines of this:

```
[{
    rangeCode: 'TEST',
    products: [{...}]
},{
    rangeCode: 'TEST2',
    products: [{...}]
}]
```

I don't understand `reduce` enough to create my version. Can it be done? If not, what is the best way to get my array of objects?

Comment: post initial `products` structure.

Comment: Your `.sort()` comparator is incorrect. The comparator should return a number, not a boolean.

Comment: thanks, changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this with:

```
function groupByRange(products) {
    products.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.rangeCode - b.rangeCode
    });

    let groups = products.reduce(function (accumulator, product) {
        let groups = accumulator.filter(item => item.rangeCode === product.rangeCode);
        let found = groups.length === 1;
        let group = found ? groups[0] : { rangeCode: product.rangeCode, products: []};

        group.products.push(product);

        if (!found) accumulator.push(group);

        return accumulator;
    }, []);

    console.log(groups);

    return groups;
}
```

hopefully that is the best way

Comment: It's hard to say if this is the best way without seeing the initial data structure, but hey, if it works for you, awesome! :) ... At least your own update/solution is simple...

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through and adding the accumulated product array.

```
let groups = [];
products.forEach(prod => {
   let acc;
   if (groups.length > 0) {
     acc = groups[groups.length-1].products.concat(prod.products);
   }
   else { // first entry into groups
     acc = prod.products;
   }
   groups.push({rangeCode: prod.rangeCode, products: acc});
}
```